# How to create 2 columns layout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create  2 columns and 2 rows layout in my page but i am having some issues.  I have used a table in which i have created 2 columns and 2 rows, that seems simple right? but my problem is that i built a gridview that has a drill down capabilities on the left side of the page and i have a chart on the right side of the page.  So when i try to use the drill down functionality in the gridview; the Chart on the right side will shift down and vise-versa.  So I want to use a very simple layout so that when I am drilling the gridview I don’t want to impact whatever I have on the right side of the page.  Can someone please show me some example of a layout where I can have 2 columns and not impacting one another?  thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a start, [don't use tables for layout](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html), it's not what they were designed for. Moving on, this isn't an ASP.net issue but one of HTML page design. [Google "CSS 2 Column layout"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=css%202%20column%20layout&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) and you will get many tutorials to choose from. Including this one:

http://css-tricks.com/super-simple-two-column-layout/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to invest in Bootstrap, you can use markup like this.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span6"> column 1 </div>
    <div class="span6"> column 2 </div>
</div>
```

Twitter Bootstrap .makes it easy to do this using the grid system, plus they provide a responsive stylesheet too.